# Apoyo en contar cumplimiento de fechas e intervalos de tiempo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla el cual muestra la fecha inscripcion del personal y las fechas de regitro(asistencia-REG1,REG2), la cual pide tener 12 consecutivas y estas deben tener un periodo de 15 a 16 dias maximo entre registro, y ver avance segun fecha de corte.

He tomado los dias a la fecha actual, e intentado hacer `IIF` con `dateadd` para restar fechas, sin embargo no me permite mas de 10 y aun no se me ocurre como medir por fecha de corte.

Del cuadro, si corto hoy, cumplirian le perosnal 1, 4 y 5, si corto al 30 de agosto cumple p 1, 2 4 5,

DATOS
BD:  **SQL Server**
NOMBRE TABLA: **PERSONAL**

```
CREATE TABLE personal
(id_personal INT, 
 Personal    VARCHAR(50), 
 f_ingreso   DATE, 
 reg1        DATE, 
 reg2        DATE, 
 reg3        DATE, 
 reg4        DATE, 
 reg5        DATE, 
 reg6        DATE, 
 reg7        DATE, 
 reg8        DATE, 
 reg9        DATE, 
 reg10       DATE, 
 reg11       DATE, 
 reg12       DATE, 
 reg13       DATE, 
 reg14       DATE
);
```

Se intento hacer

```
SELECT *, 
       IIF(DATEDIFF(dd, F_INGRESO, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 32
           AND REG1 IS NOT NULL, '1', IIF(DATEDIFF(dd, F_INGRESO, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 45 AND 47
                                          AND REG2 IS NOT NULL
                                          AND REG1 IS NOT NULL
                                          AND DATEDIFF(dd, REG1, REG2) BETWEEN 15 AND 17, '1', 0))
FROM PERSONAL;
```

Con esto consigo los que cumplen si no hubiese el tema de determianr PERIODO DE CORTE, pero solo me permite 10 lineas de `iif` (mensaje de SQL-maxima cantidad de uso)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero lo primero, ¿cómo podemos reproducir tu escenario? Edita la pregunta y agrega por lo menos la estructura de las tablas, al igual que los datos de ejemplo y todo, absolutamente todo lo que has intentado (así evitas que los usuarios recomienden cosas que ya hiciste). Aquí unas recomendaciones generales: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Y porque queres resolverlo en un query, cuando claramente necesitas un procedimiento de calculo para esto??? no todo se resuelve con sql...

Comment: Te agradeceria el apoyo en el Procedimiento, ya que en mi criterio es el script que solo se añade el periodo, pero no puedo darle buena forma